# Python regex - match everything not in mustache brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex in Python to match everything not in mustache brackets.

For example, this string:

```
This is an {{example}} for {{testing}}.
```

should produce this list of strings:

```
["This is an ", " for ", "."]
```

when used with `re.findall`.

For my mustache-matching regex, I am using this: `{{(.*?)}}`.

It seems like it should just be a simple matter of negating the above pattern, but I can't get it to work properly. I'm testing using: http://pythex.org

Thanks.

Comment: Are you escaping the `{` and `}` characters, so they actually match those characters instead of trying to treat this as a repeat count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need split

```
re.split('{{.*?}}', s)
```

Comment: Good call. I had tried using `re.split`, but the parentheses `( )` in my regex were causing the value within the brackets to also be returned. Your solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrey solution is the most simple and clearly the way to go. You have another possible way with `findall` because when the pattern contains a capture group, it returns only the capture group content:

```
re.findall(r'(?:{{.*?}})*([^{]+)', s)
```

So, if you start the pattern with an optional non-capturing group for curly brackets parts followed by a capture group for other content, `findall` returns only the capture group content and all curly brackets parts are consumed.